# Windows Phone 7 Consuming Webservice WSDL

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, wsdl

Ok I have written some basic generic webservices before but I have never tried to consume a 3rd party one. 
The one I am trying to consume is 
http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/webservices/predictions/wsdl/Predictions.wsdl

I am not getting any results back from this what so ever and cannot figure out why. 
More odd is it is not even reaching PredictionsClient_getPredictionsAndMetadataCompleted when I put a break point in the code it doesn't even reach it. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
    public void Bouy(double meters)   
    {   
        PredictionService.Parameters PredictionParams = new PredictionService.Parameters();   
        PredictionService.PredictionsPortTypeClient PredictionsClient = new PredictionService.PredictionsPortTypeClient();   

        GeoCoordinateWatcher gc = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);   
        //gc.Position.Location.Latitude, gc.Position.Location.Longitude   
        GeoCoordinate myLocation = new GeoCoordinate(27.931631,-82.802582);   


        foreach (var bl in BouyLocation.GetAll())   
        {    
            GeoCoordinate otherLocation = new GeoCoordinate(bl.Lat, bl.Lon);   

                PredictionParams.beginDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");   
                PredictionParams.endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0).ToString("yyyyMMdd");   
                PredictionParams.stationId = bl.LocationID;   
                PredictionParams.timeZone = 0;   
                PredictionParams.unit = 1;   
                PredictionParams.dataInterval = 6;   
                PredictionsClient.getPredictionsAndMetadataCompleted += new EventHandler<PredictionService.getPredictionsAndMetadataCompletedEventArgs>(PredictionsClient_getPredictionsAndMetadataCompleted);   

                PredictionsClient.getPredictionsAndMetadataAsync(PredictionParams);   


            double mymeters = myLocation.GetDistanceTo(otherLocation);   
            if (mymeters < meters)   
            {   
                TextBlock DynTextBlock = new TextBlock   
                {   
                    Name = "Appearance" + bl.LocationID,   
                    Text = bl.LocationName + PredictionResult,   
                    TextWrapping = System.Windows.TextWrapping.Wrap,   
                    Margin = new Thickness(12, -6, 12, 0),   
                    Style = (Style)Resources["PhoneTextSubtleStyle"]   

                };   

                DynamicAppearance.Children.Add(DynTextBlock);   
                this.nearByLocations.Add(new BouyLocationModel() { LocationName = bl.LocationName, LocationID = bl.LocationID, Lat = bl.Lat, Lon = bl.Lon });   
            }   
        }   
        var test = nearByLocations;   
    }   

    void PredictionsClient_getPredictionsAndMetadataCompleted(object sender, PredictionService.getPredictionsAndMetadataCompletedEventArgs e)   
    {   
        string err = e.Error.ToString();   

        PredictionResult = e.Result.ToString();   
    }
```

Comment: Try consuming this with a normal console application to see whether the problem is Windows Phone 7 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loooking at the code you have here I think that you have used the importing of a ServiceReference to auto build the classes for you?

Unfortunately I have found that this is rather temperamental on WP7 and the only way I actually got it to work was when I connected it to a Microsoft WCF service. Connecting to anything else just doesn't work.

If you do google searches there are various pages talking about the fact it doesn't work and ways around it (which I couldn't get to work).

However, there are ways around it but it isn't as simple as the auto-generated stuff. Basically you do things manually.

Although there are other ways to manually create the web service what I did was follow the information in the following which worked well: http://zetitle.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/using-reactive-extensions-with-webrequest/

You will need to parse the response yourself but XML to LINQ works really well for this.

Hope that helps, or maybe someone will have the solution as it is something I am interested in knowing how to get working too